# Angular Routing is not navigating to child route

Tags: angular, routes

I have a Menu Component, from where I am trying to navigate and load the contents of my child route - AboutComponent, which is not working. Below is my code, please help:

The URL show the proper route, there is no error in console. But the about component does not load

app.component.html:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

menu.component.html:

```
<div class="row menustyle" *ngIf="isMenuClicked">
 <div class="col24" style="padding: 0 20px">
   <ul class="nav navba-nav">
     <li>
        <a *ngFor="let data of navPathData" routerLinkActive="active" 
          routerLink="data.value"
          (click)="goto(data.value)">{{ data.text }}</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

menu.component.ts:

constructor:

```
 constructor(private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
private readonly router: Router, private dataService: DataServiceService) { }
```

method:
    public goto(value: string): void {
    //this.router.navigate();

```
this.router.navigate([value], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

}

app-routing.modulets:

```
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './content/about/about.component';

const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/menu', pathMatch: 'full' },
 {
   path: 'menu', component: MenuComponent, children:
    [
     { path: ':id', component: AboutComponent }
    ]
 }
 ];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `[routerLink]` instead of `routerLink` ? If so, you can get rid of the `goto` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are binding the routerlink to a variable you need to wrap the `routerlink` with square-brackets

```
[routerLink]="data.value"
```

Depending on the setup of your routes, you may also be specifying the relative route incorrectly, you could try `['./'+data.value]` or `['/'+data.value]`

If this is still not working you can get additional router debugging info by enabling tracing

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
      ...,
      { enableTracing: true }
    )
```

Comment: #chrismclarke I have now given :

    [routerLink]="data.value", it still doesnt work. Could yu please help me by eplaining a bit more on where to use :

    ['./'+data.value] or ['/'+data.value]

Comment: do you mean like this:

    [routerLink]="['/'+data.value]"

Comment: yes exactly like that. What do you error messages say if it's not working?

Answer (score 4):

my solution is

```
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/menu', pathMatch: 'full' },
 {
   path: 'menu', children:
    [
     { path: '', component: MenuComponent }
     { path: ':id', component: AboutComponent }
    ]
 }
 ];
```

Comment: This is correct. my mistake was the component: MenuComponent ws placed in the property where path: 'menu' is located hence the content if menu is always shown if i navigate to AboutComponent.